# Can a Core Data .sqlite backup without a WAL file be restored to operate in WAL mode?

Tags: ios, sqlite, core-data, restore, wal

Please be patient with me - I'm going to try to use the correct terminology in this question. I have an iOS app that has allowed the users to create backups of their Core Data backed .sqlite database for several years now. For some reason, way back when, I set the pragma option for journal_mode to "MEMORY", which means that each of the backups that have been made over the last several years do not have a WAL or SHM file. I am rewriting all of my database code, and I know that the current default journal_mode for iOS is "[WAL](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1809/_index.html)". When I import a backup that was made with journal_mode "MEMORY", I would like to somehow end up with that file operating in WAL mode (I want all new backups to be the same - in WAL mode) but I am not sure if this is even possible. Can a single .sqlite that has never had a WAL or SHM file be forced to start creating them? I am trying to use the NSPersistentStore methods to create backups and to restore data now, and I remember reading that the options used throughout the process (i.e. the journal_mode) need to remain consistent (I will post the link for this if I can find it). I believe, because I do not have a WAL file, that I need to use the "MEMORY" or "DELETE" journal_mode for the import. However, I am not sure if this means that the file will forever have to function without a WAL file, or if there is something I can do to get it operating in WAL mode. I hope this makes some sense - it is a bit confusing to me, but I would appreciate any thoughts on how to approach this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the journal mode of a database at any time, as long as you have exclusive access; just open it, and execute the [PRAGMA](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_journal_mode). (In fact, this is the only method to enable WAL mode.)

Please note that only WAL mode is persistently stored in the database file; any other journal mode is a property of the connection; when a non-file WAL is opened, it is in DELETE mode by default.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you.